# Cloudant: Indexes vs Views

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Are Cloudant's concept of Indexes native to CouchDB? It appears the Cloudant has built their [Index feature](https://docs.cloudant.com/guides/cloudant-query.html) on top of CouchDB, is this correct? If so, what is the difference between an Index and a View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Query interface is (currently) a simplifying API for creating and accessing the undelying CouchDB views. The indexes you define via the _index endpoint are actually translated into views, and those views can be accessed and used in the same way as a normal CouchDB view, as well as via the _find endpoint (note: the inverse is not true - Query doesn't currently use existing javascript views). The views stay in the erlang layer so gives us the opportunity for performance enhancements etc.

You can also filter result data to only return document fields you're interested in, as opposed to hard coding the returned fields in the view or running the view result through a list function.

Cheers

Simon